# Spring tutorial example - Apache excel POI export using java config

Tags: java, xml, spring, annotations, spring-java-config

I am looking at this [mkyong tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-excel-file-via-abstractexcelview/) for exporting to excel.

It looks pretty straight forward and not overly complicated.  I was able to complete all of the steps except for the last one.  The last step is a XML config step.  I have my project setup using java annotation config and the example in the tutorial is in xml.  How do I configure the following `XmlViewResolver` in 'java config' / annotaiton as opposed to xml? see code snippet below.

---

This is the part I dont know how to configure.  I am trying to get it in annotation/java config format.

**Spring Configuration**

```
<beans ...>

  <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

    <bean class="com.mkyong.common.controller.RevenueReportController" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
        <property name="location">
            <value>/WEB-INF/spring-excel-views.xml</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**File : spring-excel-views.xml**

```
<bean id="ExcelRevenueSummary"
    class="com.mkyong.common.view.ExcelRevenueReportView">
</bean>
```

---

This is what my controller looks like.

```
@Controller
public class RevenueReportController extends AbstractController{

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/exportToExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String output = ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter(request, "output");

        //dummy data
        Map<String,String> revenueData = new HashMap<String,String>();
        revenueData.put("Jan-2010", "$100,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Feb-2010", "$110,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Mar-2010", "$130,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Apr-2010", "$140,000,000");
        revenueData.put("May-2010", "$200,000,000");

        if(output ==null || "".equals(output)){
            //return normal view
            return new ModelAndView("RevenueSummary","revenueData",revenueData);

        }else if("EXCEL".equals(output.toUpperCase())){
            //return excel view
            return new ModelAndView("ExcelRevenueSummary","revenueData",revenueData);

        }else{
            //return normal view
            return new ModelAndView("RevenueSummary","revenueData",revenueData);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use the below. `@Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        XmlViewResolver resolver = new XmlViewResolver();
        resolver.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/WEB-INF/spring-excel-views.xml"));
        return resolver;
    }`

Comment: where would I put that?  what about the second xml file the spring-excel-views.xml?

Comment: I have added an answer that does not require spring-excel-views.xml. Take a look at it as well. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending my comment to original post, here is a version that does not need any xml config. With this solution you can completely eliminate the xml views. You can define you excel view as another bean and use that directly in your controller.

Config class:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.mkyong.common" })
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExcelRevenueReportView excelRevenueReportView() {
        return new ExcelRevenueReportView();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

**Contorller:**

```
@Controller
public class RevenueReportController extends AbstractController{

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    ExcelRevenueReportView excelRevenueReportView;

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/exportToExcel", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        String output = ServletRequestUtils.getStringParameter(request, "output");

        //dummy data
        Map<String,String> revenueData = new HashMap<String,String>();
        revenueData.put("Jan-2010", "$100,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Feb-2010", "$110,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Mar-2010", "$130,000,000");
        revenueData.put("Apr-2010", "$140,000,000");
        revenueData.put("May-2010", "$200,000,000");

        if(output ==null || "".equals(output)){
            //return normal view
            return new ModelAndView("RevenueSummary","revenueData",revenueData);

        }else if("EXCEL".equals(output.toUpperCase())){
            //return excel view
            new ModelAndView(excelRevenueReportView, "revenueData", revenueData);

        }else{
            //return normal view
            return new ModelAndView("RevenueSummary","revenueData",revenueData);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.  To help me understand whats happening more what is the `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` needed for?

Comment: @EnableWebMvc implementation provides spring mvc config support for your app. It provides some default implementation and if you want to override any of the defaults provided it, then you will extend WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. You may not need in your case. Its just i was using an example and came as part of copy paste.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the changes as below:

**Create a new configuration class:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mkyong.common")
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    ServletContext servletContext;

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getXmlViewResolver() {
        XmlViewResolver resolver = new XmlViewResolver();
        resolver.setLocation(new ServletContextResource(servletContext,
                    "/WEB-INF/spring-excel-views.xml"));
        return resolver;
    }    
}
```

**Annotate your controller class with `@Controller`**

```
@Controller
public class RevenueReportController extends AbstractController {

}
```

The `spring-excel-views.xml` remains the same as you are using `XmlViewResolver`. It expects the bean definition to be in XML file.

Comment: thanks for your feedback.  I think this is close.  however I have one problem.  This line `resolver.setLocation(new ServletContextResource(ServletContext,"/WEB-INF/spring-excel-views.xml"));`  it doesnot recognise `ServletContext` says that there is an expression expected?

Comment: I copy pasted the code snippet from the answer into eclipse. I could not find any compilation errors. Please check if something is missing in your version of code.

Comment: I missed out the @autowiring of context aware.  configuration is working now.  thanks Mithun

Comment: @Mithun, take a look at my answer which does not need spring-excel-views.xml.